# MySQL Query - Include dates without records

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have a report that displays a graph. The X axis uses the date from the below query. Where the query returns no date, I am getting gaps and would prefer to return a value. Is there any way to force a date where there are no records?

```
SELECT
    DATE(instime),
    CASE
        WHEN direction = 1 AND duration > 0 THEN 'Incoming'
        WHEN direction = 2 THEN 'Outgoing'
        WHEN direction = 1 AND duration = 0 THEN 'Missed'
    END AS type,
    COUNT(*)
FROM taxticketitem
GROUP BY
    DATE(instime),
    CASE
        WHEN direction = 1 AND duration > 0 THEN 'Incoming'
        WHEN direction = 2 THEN 'Outgoing'
        WHEN direction = 1 AND duration = 0 THEN 'Missed'
    END
ORDER BY DATE(instime)
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "make dates with no records?"

Comment: Do you mean that `instime` is NULL in your database (in which case look up `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`, or do you mean there are some days for there are no records in your database? If that's the case, go with the answer @SalmanA suggests below.

Comment: you can set the default for your date column to be now() or current_date

Comment: So for example, there could be no records available for Sunday. So on a chart from data running from Friday to today (Tuesday), the chart would graph data on Friday, Saturday, Monday and Tuesday. Leaving out Sunday completely. If there was some way of forcing a zero for Sunday or any missing dates, it would make the graphing more clear when viewed by users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to create a table of dates and `LEFT JOIN` your table with them. The table could look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `datelist` (
 `date` DATE NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
);
```

and filled with all dates between, say Jan-01-2000 through Dec-31-2050 (here is my [**Date Generator script**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a25b1/1)).

Next, write your query like this:

```
SELECT datelist.date, COUNT(taxticketitem.id) AS c
FROM datelist
LEFT JOIN taxticketitem ON datelist.date = DATE(taxticketitem.instime)
WHERE datelist.date BETWEEN `2012-01-01` AND `2012-12-31`
GROUP BY datelist.date
ORDER BY datelist.date
```

`LEFT JOIN` and counting not null values from right table's ensures that the count is correct (0 if no row exists for a given date).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a set of dates to `LEFT JOIN` your table to it. Unfortunately, MySQL lacks a way to generate it on the fly.

You would need to prepare a table with, say, 100000 consecutive integers from 0 to 99999 (or how long you think your maximum report range would be):

```
CREATE TABLE series (number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

and use it like this:

```
SELECT  DATE(instime) AS r_date, CASE ... END AS type, COUNT(instime)
FROM    series s
LEFT JOIN
        taxticketitems ti
ON      ti.instime >= '2013-01-01' + INTERVAL number DAY
        AND ti.instime < '2013-01-01' + INTERVAL number + 1 DAY
WHERE   s.number <= DATEDIFF('2013-02-01', '2013-01-01')
GROUP BY
        r_date, type
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to do something similar before.

You need to have a subselect to generate a range of dates. All the dates you want. Easiest with a start date added to a number:-

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(SomeStartDate, INTERVAL (a.I + b.1 * 10) DAY)
FROM integers a, integers b
```

Given a table called integers with a single column called i with 10 rows containing 0 to 9 that SQL will give you a range of 100 days starting at *SomeStartDate*

You can then left join your actual data against that to get the full range.