# Group by Date returning 0 if null data Mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 table

`Donasi` and `sistem_list_Date`.

This is my query

```
$this->db->SELECT("sistem_list_tanggal.tanggal, COUNT(id) AS jumlah")
                ->FROM('sistem_list_tanggal')
                ->JOIN('donasi','donasi.tanggal_ambil=sistem_list_tanggal.tanggal','LEFT')
                ->WHERE('sistem_list_tanggal.tanggal >=', '2019-12-01')
                ->WHERE('sistem_list_tanggal.tanggal <=', '2019-12-31')
                ->WHERE('status',1)
                ->GROUP_BY('sistem_list_tanggal.tanggal');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $output = array('data' => array());
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result_array();
        }else{
            return array();
        }
```

Why this query returning only date with value (jumlah).

[image: screenshot1-output query]

I want query return all dates 2019-12-01 until 2019-12-31, if null data return 0

I have followed the tutorial here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14336188/11540418

Comment: You'll need a calendar table..

Answer (score 0):

YOU have to use left join for the same query